# Limiting SharePoint Search Engine to a specific subsite

Tags: sharepoint

I have a site that has several subsites . Let's say company's main intranet site with finance, information technology , HR etc as subsites.I need to limit users to have search only within the specific site . Lets say when a person searches from the finance department the results should come only from that department. But i want them to hav access to all departments, but the search result should be of their own department

Answer (score 3):

You should create custom scopes and add conditions on those scopes limiting results to those coming from the specific URLs. When searching each scope, the users will only see results with URLs containing the starting URL you defined. You can also limit the scopes the users see in the scope selector (or hide the selector), you need to replace the search box embedded in the master page (it's a delegate control) with your own search box (same control, just with your own parameters).

Comment: could you elaborate how to create the scopes

Comment: Just go to search settings (under SSP) there you will see a section for scopes. create a new scope and add a condition requiring the URL to contain your site URL. compile the scopes and add them to the site collection search box (under site collection settings --> scopes)