# Sharepoint 2010 search scopes Information

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-search

I have a webappa and it has 4 site collections: A, B , C, B.

I want to have a Advanced search in site A where user can search content of A and B site collection but user should not be able to search this content in C site collection.

If I create a content source with urls of site collection A and B then how would I be able to restrict the user to search this in only site A

Answer (score 1):

You can add Crawl rules for the search service application to restrict search result from particular site collection.

Way to create:

```
Go to central admin -> Search service application -> Crawl Rules.
```

Click `New crawl rules` and give the URL which is not be searched and click `Exclude all items` in the path in the Crawl coniguration setting

Click `OK` and `Restart crawl`.

Answer (score 0):

May Be this answer can help you

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287183/limiting-sharepoint-search-engine-to-a-specific-subsite
```